# Google Fit: Agregate data grows with each query

Tags: java, android, google-fit

It's something that just decieves me. I'm using sample code from Google Fit site and documentation. The main correction I made from one sample is that I created a timespan of one month instead one week.

```
    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(this.getGoogleClient(), readRequest)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataReadResult result) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        RangedStepsReport report = null;
                        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Google Fit: Report obtained");
                            java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT);
                            report = new RangedStepsReport(startTime, endTime);
                            //
                            for (Bucket b : result.getBuckets()) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Bucket: " + b.getBucketType());
                                Log.i(TAG, "Activity: " + b.getActivity());
                                Log.i(TAG, "StartDate: " + dateFormat.format(b.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                                Log.i(TAG, "EndDate: " + dateFormat.format(b.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                                Log.i(TAG, "Activity: " + b.getSession());
                                for (DataSet ds : b.getDataSets()) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "\tData set:" + ds.getDataType());
                                    Log.i(TAG, "\tSource:" + ds.getDataSource());

                                    for (DataPoint dp : ds.getDataPoints()) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "\tData point:");
                                        Log.i(TAG, "\t\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
                                        Log.i(TAG, "\t\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                                        Log.i(TAG, "\t\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                                        for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                                            Log.i(TAG, "\t\t\tField: " + field.getName() + " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                            //
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Google Fit: Report NOT obtained!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

This should be the best way to get a list of steps from GoogleFit doesn't matter how many step sensor the device has.

Then I get different values for the same day for different queries I made during the day (executing the exact same code).

```
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Bucket: 1
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Activity: in_vehicle
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: StartDate: 3/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: EndDate: 4/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Activity: null
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Data set:DataType{com.google.step_count.delta[steps(i)]}
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Source:DataSource{derived:Application{com.google.android.gms::null}:aggregated:DataType{com.google.step_count.delta[steps(i)]}}
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Data point:
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       Type: com.google.step_count.delta
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       Start: 3/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       End: 4/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:           Field: steps Value: 6097
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Bucket: 1
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Activity: in_vehicle
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: StartDate: 4/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: EndDate: 5/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Activity: null
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Data set:DataType{com.google.step_count.delta[steps(i)]}
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Source:DataSource{derived:Application{com.google.android.gms::null}:aggregated:DataType{com.google.step_count.delta[steps(i)]}}
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Data point:
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       Type: com.google.step_count.delta
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       Start: 4/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       End: 5/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:           Field: steps Value: 22162
```

Then the same query

```
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Bucket: 1
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Activity: in_vehicle
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: StartDate: 3/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: EndDate: 4/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Activity: null
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Data set:DataType{com.google.step_count.delta[steps(i)]}
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Source:DataSource{derived:Application{com.google.android.gms::null}:aggregated:DataType{com.google.step_count.delta[steps(i)]}}
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Data point:
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       Type: com.google.step_count.delta
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       Start: 3/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       End: 4/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:           Field: steps Value: 5994
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Bucket: 1
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Activity: in_vehicle
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: StartDate: 4/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: EndDate: 5/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil: Activity: null
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Data set:DataType{com.google.step_count.delta[steps(i)]}
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Source:DataSource{derived:Application{com.google.android.gms::null}:aggregated:DataType{com.google.step_count.delta[steps(i)]}}
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:   Data point:
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       Type: com.google.step_count.delta
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       Start: 4/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:       End: 5/5/16
/<pack.....> I/GoogleFitUtil:           Field: steps Value: 22181
```

Notice of One day the fields tend to go up, the other day the fields tend to go down. Doesn it have to do with the time in which I inject the condition?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Answered in Google Fit -[Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://developers.google.com/fit/faq#how_do_i_get_the_same_step_count_as_the_google_fit_app), values for step/distance/active time/calories do not match those of Fit app could be caused by different versions of updates which should match up after a couple of syncs and aside from that, it could also be caused by not reading the proper data sources wherein a suggested code was given.